# PHP Google_Client insert youtube playlistItem (2-leg-oauth)

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-api, google-oauth, google-api-php-client

My web using the `PHP Google_Client` to insert the youtube playlistItem in my playlist (2-leg-oauth),
and get the error 
`Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method.`
Where can I setting the server using `my-account@gmail.com` to have the same permission to access google api 
such like insert playlistItem,
or is there having another way without using `my-account@gmail.com` to get same permission?

PHP Code:

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=client_secret.json');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube');
$client->setSubject('my-account@gmail.com');
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you have delegated domain-wide access to the service account and
>   you want to impersonate a user account, specify the email address of
>   the user account use
>
> ```
> $client->setSubject($user_to_impersonate);
> ```

The YouTube API doesn't support delegated domain-wide access or service accounts.  You will need to authenticate with Oauth2.

see [PHP Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/php)

Answer (score 0):

You're hitting a common problem. Many developers think that a Service Account is the correct way for server apps to communicate to Google's API services for a given Google account. It isn't! A Service Account, as its name implies, is a brand new account (actually a kind of half-account since you can't actually log in to it) that is dedicated to your app.

What you need to do is a one-time procedure to generate a Refresh Token, which you will store securely. Thereafter, whenever you need to access a Google API such as YouTube, you will use that Refresh Token to generate an Access Token, which you will include in each API request. The steps are enumerated [How do I authorise an app (web or installed) without user intervention? (canonical ?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention-canonic) and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hfWe1gPCnzc